# How to add my custom css class to a html element

Tags: html, css, socialengine

I am new to Social Engine. Part of the HTML seems to come from the modules/views directory and part of it seems to be generated on the run.

I did look into creating new theme, it allows to write new styles of the existing CSS classes. Is that all that is possible?. I also hear it allows to add new html through creating widgets but if I write a new CSS class how do I add it to an existing html element? (because I see some CSS classes are used on different pages so the style I write for a class to suit one page doesn't give what I require on another ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SocialEngine doesn't allow HTML modification of the built-in templates. In order to write a CSS definition for a specific element, I suggest using [CSS specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) as a way to make your styles more specialized.

Answer (score 1):

You can't edit HTML code in admin (you can edit source files, but it is tricky way).
You can edit CSS in the theme editor: /admin/themes
There are 2 related files you can edit: constants.css and theme.css
You can overwrite any existing CSS rule here or create new.
And yes, you can create new theme from scratch :)
Look in the SE KB for example: http://support.socialengine.com/questions/128/Creating-Your-Own-Theme